# Estimate one regression coefficient for different variables

Tags: regression, regression-coefficients, predictor

I would like to know whether it is possible to compute one identical coefficient for three different variables in a regression. So instead of estimating $\beta_1$, $\beta_2$, $\beta_3$ here:

$$
Y=\beta_0 + \beta_1 x_1 + \beta_2 x_2 + \beta_3 x_3 + e
$$

I would like to estimate one single coefficient from $x_1$, $x_2$, $x_3$. Is this possible?

Comment: What do you mean by a single coefficient? Do you mean whether or not it is possible to estimate a regression where all of the slopes are the same value, or estimating a coefficient that somehow aggregates the effect of three predictors into one coefficient?

Comment: Algebraically manipulate the expression in your question so $\beta_1$ only appears once. It's the easiest approach by far.

Comment: sum $x_1+x_2+x_3$ and use as predictor?